# Where my Registry entry go ? windows 7, win64

Tags: windows-7, registry, win64

Windows7 and Win64 is a new platform me, programming wise, so don't know what happened, I save a key in windows registry in windows7 64bit with the following command, the problem is that the same code is able to return REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY return value, which means the key creation was success and that the function is able to read/open the key in subsequent calls, but when I try to find the key in the location in regedit.exe, I can't it simply doesn't show in the tree neither in HKLM_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/MyProject nor in HKLM_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Wow6432Node/MyProject

Can anybody please clear what's happening here ?

```
 HKEY hKey ;
 HKEY  key = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
 DWORD disValue ;
 string subKey = "Software\\MyProject\\";

 LONG retValue = RegCreateKeyEx( key, subKey.c_str(), 0, 0, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0, &hKey, &disValue ) ;
 if ( retValue == ERROR_SUCCESS )
 {
    if ( disValue == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY )// new key created. This value will change to REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY if the key already existed, the function then simply open the key.
       return true;
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Are you running as Administrator? Have you fallen foul of registry virtualization?

Comment: @Roger No I am not, neither is my program, even when i run regedit.exe as administrator, I can't see the entry. Not sure what registry visualization is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your process is not running as Administrator, it will be unable to access `HKLM\SOFTWARE`. For compatibility reasons, Windows Vista and Windows 7 will then apply something called "[registry virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)". This redirects accesses to HKLM\SOFTWARE to somewhere that your process *can* access. It does something similar for legacy processes that attempt to write to `C:\Program Files`.

How does Windows decide that your application is "legacy" and needs this compatibility hack? You need an [application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa374191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to tell Windows that your process is Windows Vista-aware and that you don't want the hack.

Comment: I have posted the changes below, please have a look. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following manifest file to the project and added **CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "MyProject.exe.Manifest"** to the resource.rc file. And voila.

```
**MyProject.exe.Manifest**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly
  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
  manifestVersion="1.0">

<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
      <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows Vista functionality -->
    <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
      <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 7 functionality-->
    <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
    </application> 
</compatibility>

<assemblyIdentity
    name="MyCompany.Apps.MyProject"
    processorArchitecture="*"
    version="1.0.0.0"
    type="win32"/>
<description>App description</description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        processorArchitecture="*"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
    />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
        level="requireAdministrator"
        uiAccess="false"/>
    </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```